# Ruby on Rails: Dropdown search - invalid input syntax for type boolean: "%%"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, syntax

I'm trying to build a search function where the user can search on different fields, eg. client, industry, technology using drop down menus. The search function was working until I decided to allow users to search for more than one technology at a time.

Here is my model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tech2, :tech3, :tech4, :tech5, :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech



def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech, search_tech2, search_tech3, search_tech4, search_tech5 , search_business_div, search_project_owner,  search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present? || search_industry.present? || search_role.present? || search_tech.present? || search_tech2.present? || search_tech3.present? || search_tech4.present? || search_tech5.present? || search_business_div.present? || search_project_owner.present? || search_status.present? ||  search_keywords.present?


where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND (tech LIKE ? OR ? OR ? OR ? OR ? ) AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%"  , "%#{search_tech2}%" , "%#{search_tech3}%"  , "%#{search_tech4}%" , "%#{search_tech5}%" ,"%#{search_business_div}%" , 
      "%#{search_project_owner}%"  , "%#{search_status}%", 
       "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])



end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

and here is my search action in my project controller:

```
def search


@search = params[:client], params[:industry], params[:role], params[:tech], params[:tech2],params[:tech3],params[:tech4],params[:tech5], params[:business_div], params[:project_owner], params[:status], params[:keywords]

@project_search = Project.search(*@search).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

@search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty? 

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])


respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

I am getting this error when trying to search for a technology:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Projects#search

    PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "%%"
LINE 1: ...ND role LIKE '%%' AND (tech LIKE '%Telephony%' OR '%%' OR '%...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE (client LIKE '%%' AND industry LIKE '%%' AND role LIKE '%%' AND (tech LIKE '%Telephony%' OR '%%' OR '%%' OR '%%' OR '%%' ) AND business_div LIKE '%%' AND project_owner LIKE '%%' AND status LIKE '%%' AND keywords LIKE '%%')

Extracted source (around line #169):

166: 
167: <% if @project_search.total_entries > 0 %>
168: <% if @search_performed %>
169: 
170: <style>
171: CSS3 Code
172:
```

I think it's something to do with the other technology dropdown menus returning null. Hopefully someone can see the problem. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech, search_tech2, search_tech3, search_tech4, search_tech5, search_business_div, search_project_owner,  search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords)
    # start with a scoped query, to apply more scopes on it afterwards
    _projects = Project.scoped 
    # then, for each of the parameters, apply the scope only if present
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end
    if search_industry.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['industry LIKE ?', like(search_industry)]
    end
    if search_role.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['role LIKE ?', like(search_role)]
    end

    # here lies the problem. you search in the 'tech' column, but you seem to want to search in many columns...
    search_techs = [search_tech, search_tech2, 
          search_tech3, search_tech4, 
          search_tech5].select(&:present?).compact
    if search_techs.present?
      sql = (['tech LIKE ?'] * search_techs.size).join(" OR ")
      args = search_techs.collect {|t| like(t)}
      _projects = _projects.where [sql, *args]
    end
    if search_business_div.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['business_div LIKE ?', like(search_business_div)]
    end
    if search_project_owner.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['project_owner LIKE ?', like(search_project_owner)]
    end

     if search_status.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['status LIKE ?', like(search_status)]
    end



todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = nil
    search_start_date_dd = nil

    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = nil
end

        if search_start_date_dd.blank?

      _projects = _projects.where [' DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B]
    end


        if search_start_date_A.blank? or search_start_date_B.blank?
      _projects = _projects.where ['DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_dd, todays_date]
    end




    if search_keywords.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['keywords LIKE ?', like(search_keywords)]
    end
    # now you have applied only the present scopes. return the result, and watch 
    # the query as it executes.
    _projects
  end
```

Comment: Bad, bad, bad…tsk, tsk, tsk: `:tech2, :tech3, :tech4, :tech5`. There is a many-to-many relationship between `tech` and `projects`. Model it as such and your thoughts should clear up.

Comment: I attempted to. I asked a question, but I found it too difficult to explain what I was trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636413/ruby-on-rails-searching-two-models-in-one-search

I thought it would be easier restricting the user to 5 technology menus. I am very new to rails you see.

Comment: You shouldn't include a variable in the query unless it has a value, or you should supply a default value, so the sql is valid.

Comment: They recommended you use one of the existing search solutions, which would be a very good idea. You're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You query is not valid according to the sql syntax.

```
tech LIKE '%1%' OR '%2%' OR '%3%'
```

Try this instead:

```
tech LIKE '%1%' OR tech LIKE '%2%' OR tech LIKE '%3%'
```

Comment: This is only searching on the first technology column of the table. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your search method can be written a lot better, it will help you to find the issues (which depend basically on useless LIKEs.

But you are making the databse something that is not his job. So many LIKEs are the tombstone of any RDBMS. Use a full-text search tool like solr, the API is easier, and it will work much better!

Here there is an almost equivalent `search` method, where every LIKE is added only if needed.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, 
                  search_tech, search_tech2, search_tech3, search_tech4, 
                  search_tech5, search_business_div, search_project_owner,
                  search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, 
                  search_start_date_B,  search_keywords)
    # start with a scoped query, to apply more scopes on it afterwards
    _projects = Project.scoped 
    # then, for each of the parameters, apply the scope only if present
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end
    if search_industry.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['industry LIKE ?', like(search_industry)]
    end
    if search_role.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['role LIKE ?', like(search_role)]
    end
    if search_industry.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['industry LIKE ?', like(search_industry)]
    end
    # here lies the problem. you search in the 'tech' column, but you seem to want to search in many columns...
    search_techs = [search_tech, search_tech2, 
          search_tech3, search_tech4, 
          search_tech5].select(&:present?).compact
    if search_techs.present?
      sql = (['tech LIKE ?'] * search_techs.size).join(" OR ")
      args = search_techs.collect {|t| like(t)}
      _projects = _projects.where [sql, *args]
    end
    if search_business_div.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['business_div LIKE ?', like(search_business_div)]
    end
    if search_project_owner.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['project_owner LIKE ?', like(search_project_owner)]
    end
    if search_status.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['status LIKE ?', like(search_status)]
    end
    if search_keywords.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['keywords LIKE ?', like(search_keywords)]
    end
    # now you have applied only the present scopes. return the result, and watch 
    # the query as it executes.
    _projects
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I use this technique, I get this error: `undefined local variable or method _project for #<Class:0xb643484>`

Comment: sorry, a typo in the last line of the method. Add an "s" to the variable name.

Comment: That seems to work now. Thank you. Can you suggest how I can get rid of the blank entries in the tech columns. I have 5 dropdown menus in my "create new project" page, and if the user doesn't select 5 technologies, the empty dropdowns get submitted as blank, and are now showing up in the tech search dropdowns